# Satellite Internet

Tags: wireless, internet

This is a long shot question but would it be possible to take your home wifi, hook it up to a transmitter that broadcasts to a satellite, and then the satellite would broadcast down to your phone, giving you service anywhere but with your home internet?[image: Wifi Diagram]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su],

Answer (score 2):

That won’t work, satellite and WiFi are very different protocols using different physical transmitters and receivers as well as different protocols to communicate.

Comment: So couldn't you just get something that would translate the different protocols?

Comment: No, it requires very different hardware.